# Why I cannot get the data from UserController to my user.blade.php file in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I need some help I am learning Laravel 9 and I have a problem, in the UserController I declare a public function show with a parameter $id and return it in user.blade.php file and  call using template literals, my problem is I cannot get the data inside my function show.

This is the codein UserController file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
 public function show($id){
  $data = array([
   "id" => $id,
   "name" => "John Doe",
   "age" => 22,
   "email" => "jhondoe@gmail.com"
  ]);
  return view("user", $data);
  }
}
```

web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/show/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

user.blade.php file

```
{{ $data }}
```

it says

> "ErrorException Undefined variable $data"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Nfw.png)

Comment: While you're passing in the variable named `$data`, it's not being registered as `$data`. It should be `['data' => $data]` See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: `$data` is an associative array of `'id'`, `'name`', etc. `$data` is not available as a variable, `$id`, `$name`, etc. are. Change to `['data' => $data]`, or reference your variables correctly.

Comment: You also have `array([ ... ])`, which is a nested Array `[['id' => ..., 'name' => ...]]`; is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view function expects an associative array as second parameter (see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views)). Each key of the array will have an equivalent variable in your blade view.

So you should respond either be :

```php
return view("user", ['data' => $data]);
```

Or use PHP's `compact` [helper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

```php
return view("user", compact('data'));
```

Or change your view so that it uses

```php
{{ $id }}
{{ $name }}
{{ $age }}
{{ $email }}
```

Do whatever makes more sense to your use case

Comment: Your answer is correct, except your point on *"[...] expects an array as second parameter"* - `$data` **IS** an array.

Comment: @TimLewis Nice catch, I updated my answer